# l'Hopital's rule and function with two or more arguments

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, asymptotics, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to use l'Hopital's rule to compare two functions, for example $f(x, y)$ and $g(x, y)$ when $x, y \rightarrow \infty$?

I've tried to search over the web but found nothing.

Comment: L'hopital's rule cannot be used for multivariable limits.

Comment: @TomHimler could you provide a link or at least name of the method what should I use to solve this kind of limits?

Comment: I would search up polar coordinates or the two-path test. That may help answer your question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177067/lhospital-rule-for-two-variable.Have a look.

Comment: @TomHimler let's say that we have limit (x, y -> inf) like $${x^2 + y^2 + y}\over {x + x^2 + y}$$ can I say that this is equal to $${x^2 + y^2 }\over {x^2 + y}$$

Comment: @PeterSzilas thank you! Could you also take a look at my previous comment?

Comment: No Name Yp. Careful , you try to manipulate the fraction, example:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947409/how-to-show-that-limit-value-exists/2947440#2947440

Comment: No Name Yp.Have a look at worked out examples ,there are quite a few, to get some practice .Let me know.